# FEM-Space is a dense subset of $H^{k+\frac{3}{2}-\varepsilon}$

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, hilbert-spaces

I have a finite element space $V_h^k:=\lbrace v \in C^k([0,1]):v_{|I_i} \in \mathbb{P}_{k+1}\rbrace$ where $h$ is a mesh on $[0,1]$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$, $[0,1]= \bigcup_{i=0}^{n}I_i$.

Does someone know where i can find proofs for the following statements:

1. $V_h^k$ is a (dense) subset of $H^{k+1}$
2. $V_h^k$ is a (dense) subset of $H^{k+\frac{3}{2}-\varepsilon}$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$.

I is clear that $V_h^k$ is a subset of $H^{k+1}$ but i don't know how to show the statements and was not able to find the corresponding proofs.

I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: What textbook/paper are you reading from? Is this a statement that is used in that book/paper without proof?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. That is not from a book or a paper. Thats the reason why i search for a book or a paper that includes this.

Comment: Oh, I have absolutely no clue of where you could read it from, then. The only thing that comes to mind is a mesh method for solving PDEs, like the Galerkin method or something. It is also possible that it may be proved in a manner similar to elementary results in this field, and so is not quite expounded on anywhere. (Also, I did not ask, but I don't know what $\mathbb P_{k+1}$ means either, never seen the notation).

Comment: $\mathbb{P}_{k+1}$ is defined as the space of all polynomials of degree $k+1$. 
So the Space $V_h^k$ is then the space of all splines of degree k. 
The Question occurred because i was wondering why i can approximate functions in $H^{k+1}$ and $H^{k+\frac{3}{2}-\varepsilon}$ by splines.

So i assumed that the space $V_h$ has to be dense ?

But i'm not sure if this is even true.

Comment: Oh, so you are guessing that these results are true? But then again, I would also do the same!